# Lexically sorting a linked-list of Strings

Tags: java, list, sorting, linked-list, mergesort

Given a string, seperted by a single space, I need to transfer each word in the String to a Node in a linked list, and keep the list sorted lexically (like in a dictionary).

The first step I did is to move through the String, and put every word in a seperate Node. Now, I'm having a hard time sorting the list - it has to be done in the most efficient way.

Merge-sort is nlogn. Merge-sort would be the best choice here?

Comment: A better approach would be to implement an `insert` function that attempts to insert each word in the correct order in the linked list.

Comment: "...and keep the list sorted lexically." That sounds like you need to keep it sorted for each insertion. Are you sure you're allowed to sort it once after all words are inserted?

Comment: I tried to do this while going through the text, but the problem is that it's only possible to add a new word to the start or to the end, no? Each check will require another loop (to know where to insert the new word)..

Comment: insertion sort is O(n^2), isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you had a list and wanted to sort it merge sort is a good solution. But in your case you can make it better.
You have a string separated by spaces and you break it and put it in list's nodes. Then you want to sort the list.
You can do better by combining both steps.
1) Have a linked list with head and tail and pointers to previous node.
2) As you extract a word from the sentence store the word in the list in inserted order. I mean you start from the tail or head of the list depending on if it is larger or smaller than these elements and go forward until you reach an element larger/smaller than the current one. Insert it at that location. You just update the pointers.

Comment: Thanks, sounds very logical.
One more question: if the only attribute I can use in the class List is "head", can I still use your approach? (can't add another attribute except for the head). What I'm allowed to touch is the Node iteself (not the list). In the Node class itself, I have only textual value and a pointer to the next Node.. So I guess it doesn't work here :S

Comment: @Osh24:If you have only head you can still do it but it is a bit more tricky. You would need to start moving forward from head and keep a pointer of the `next->next` element so when you want to put something in between 2 nodes because that is its place you won't lose any element's reference

Comment: I don't get it. Let's say we have "Hello Beautiful World". I'm starting to go through the String, "Hello" -> setting the head pointer to "Hello" Node. Then, "Beautiful". Lexically before "H", so I am making a new Node "Beautiful", where its next is "Hello", then set the head to Beautiful. What's next? "World" should be last, I'm not sure how to approach that situation.

Comment: And what if I have more than 3 words? Getting to the last Node will require passing through the entire list, no?

Comment: @Osh24:Originally you have an empty list so you add `Hello->NULL`. Then you have beautiful and you start traversing the list until you find an element that is bigger than what you currently have. In this case you find `Hello` bigger and stop there so you have `Beatiful->Hello->NULL`. Then you have `World` and start traversing the list and you see that it is bigger than `Beatiful` so you keep on going, bigger than `Hello`, keep going and reach the end of list so you add it there and end up with `Beatiful->Hello->World->NULL`. Basically it is same reasoning as insert sort

Comment: @Osh24:Yes you would need to traverse the whole list. That is why I mentioned head/tail in the answer

Comment: I see, so it's less efficient than mergeSort.. I guess merge sort is the most efficient way, concerning these limitations. Thanks!

Comment: @Osh24:You could put the words in an array and sort the array and then add them to the list. Are you allowed to do that?

Comment: If I do that, the space complexity is O(n), and what about the time complexity? I would still get to O(nlogn), So I guess it's better to do it with inserting straight into the list and then merge sorting, for O(1) space..? :P

Comment: @Osh24:You can not do better than O(NlogN) when sorting. It is the lower bound you can get.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know about the space complexity. Using an array will cost space. So, to sum it up - go for the original plan? 1. Adding the words (without sorting) to the list. 2. MergeSort the list.

Comment: @Osh24:Yes, I think so

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built-in [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)), which is a mergesort implementation. More specifically:

> This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays.

Comment: Thanks, but they require that we write the code on our own (preparation for an exam). Anyway, mergesort is the most efficient way for this kind of problem, true?

Comment: That's a really surprising algorithm. Don't most built-in sorting methods use a variation of Quick Sort?